# Generate Dictionary in Python at run time

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to generate dictionary in python dynamically.

```
dict_users = {1 : { "name" : "MTaqi", "email" : "taqi.official@gmail.com" , "phone" : "03455097679"},
     2 : { "name" : "Ali Naqi", "email" : "ali.naqi@gmail.com" , "phone" : "03455097679" },
     3 : { "name" : "M. Turab", "email" : "turab.hassan@gmail.com" , "phone" : "4534534535" }}
```

One thing comes in my mind that what if I create a dictinary of these data and then assign that list to dict like this.

```
key-dict = { "name" : "MTaqi", "email" : "taqi.official@gmail.com" , "phone" : "03455097679"}
and then 
dict_users = { 1 : {key-dict}, 1: {key-dict}}
```

the main task is to get users data from database and store them in dictionreis

Comment: define dynamically here???

Comment: *(of a process or system) characterized by constant change, activity, or progress.* \*win\*

Comment: as i mention in my question, the data i coming from db via query and have to store in dictionary as describe above.

Comment: Try this: `dict_users = {i: {'name': raw_input('Get name: '), 'email':raw_input('Get email: '), 'phone':raw_input('Get phone number: ')} for i in range(3)}` replacing `raw_input()` with `db_query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dict constructor

```
d = dict(key1=val1, key2=val2)
```

or __setitem__ method

```
d = {}
d['key1'] = val1
d['key2'] = val2
```

There are other, even more flexible ways, but those are the basics.